# Checking existence of a txt file with C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file

First of all, i'd to establish that i do have the text file in my Folders directory. Im using visual studio and it is where my source code is compiling.

The code below should demonstate why its not working. In visual studio.

```
int main( const int argc, const char **argv )
{
    char usrMenuOption;
    const char *cFileName = argv[ 1 ];
    checkName( cFileName );  // supplying the checkName function with contents of argv[1]

    usrMenuOption = getUsrOption();  // calling another function

    fgetc(stdin);
         return 0;
}
ifstream *openInputFile( const char *cFileName )
{
    // this function might be the pronblem.
    ifstream *inFile;
    inFile = new ifstream; 
    inFile->open( cFileName, ios::in );
    return inFile;
}
bool checkName( const char *cFileName )
{
    // it works fine if i use a regular ifstream obj and not the one from the function
    ifstream *inFile;
    inFile = openInputFile( cFileName );
    inFile->open( cFileName, ios::in );

    if ( inFile->good() )
    { 
        return true;
    }
    else
    { 
        cout << '"' << cFileName << '"' << ": File does not exist! " << endl;
        return false;
    }         
}
```

It does work if i use a non-pointer object for the ifstream.
however i need to open all of my input files this way, using the function i made.
I'm a little confused because i did not have this issue compiling in dev-cpp

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with it? If it doesn't compile, where does the compiler complain and about what? If it doesn't run, what's it doing unexpectedly?

Comment: You mean other than the resource leak? :)

Comment: Yes, and other than that it crashes if you start it without parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always check ifs.is_open() where ifs is a ifstream.

Answer (score 13):

You have a few options:

1. The one you've tried - opening the file.
2. Using [stat](http://www.techbytes.ca/techbyte103.html).
3. Using [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx).
4. Using [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx).

The only way to guarantee that it exists **and that you can use it** is to open it. If you use other methods you end up with a race condition (because the file could be deleted or locked after you check to see if it exists.

**EDIT**: You have a couple of other issues in your code. Firstly, you allocate a `infile` via `new`, but you never `delete` it. Secondly, you call `open` twice.

Comment: +1.  Just try opening the file -- that will either work or fail.  Don't even bother using a separate checkName() function, get rid of it.

Comment: @OJ If the file is open, then it could not be deleted?

Answer (score 3):

That's a poor way to test for existence: because if the file is open by another process, then the file exists but you can't open it.

A better way to test might be to use the [GetFileAttributes Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx): if it doesn't return `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` then the file exists.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using Boost, there is a simple function boost::filesystem::exists( path ) that would be useful to you I guess !

Answer (score 1):

To check for the existence of a file (POSIX.1 compliant):

```
#include <unistd.h>

if (! access (file_name, F_OK))
{
  // File exists.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[How do i check if a file exists using ANSI C++?](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/print-thread/313562)

```
#include <fstream>

inline bool FileExists(const char * filename)
{
    return std::ifstream(filename);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to open the file twice inside `checkName()`: the first time in the constructor call inside the call to `openInputFile()`, the second time inside `checkName()` itself.  Why the second call to `open()`?

I don't know what happens when an `ifstream` with an already-open file attempts to `open()` another file, but it won't be good, and it may well depend on the exact library implementation (hence the different behaviour between Dev-C++ and MSVC++).  In short, **don't do it**.

There is at least one other bug: You aren't closing `inFile` anywhere inside `checkName()`.

### But Anyway, Do This Instead

Really, it's better not to have a separate `checkName()` function -- just have `openInputFile()` attempt to open the file, and if it fails, report the error right there and/or return a `NULL` pointer (or even throw an exception).  That way, the operation is "atomic" -- as things stand, if the file exists at the time `checkName()` is called but is deleted before a subsequent call to `openInputFile()`, your code will get very confused.